# Xilinx primitives for DDR3 memory controller

Tags: fpga, xilinx, ddr, ddr3, spartan-6

I have finished simulating a Micron DDR3 controller,

the DDR3 schematics and verilog code are located at https://github.com/promach/DDR

However, I have concern on implementing it on the Spartan-6_XC6SLX16_FTG256 FPGA.

Besides [ODDR2 primitive](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx14_7/spartan6_hdl.pdf#page=224) , what other primitives do I need in this case ?

Comment: If you need to ask, you really should be using the Xilinx MIG, or [Memory Interface Generator](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/ip_documentation/mig/v3_92/ug416.pdf). It knows how to combine the hard-core memory controller with PL to implement various kinds of memory interfaces.

Comment: @DaveTweed  What does it mean by "The ODDR2 has an optional alignment feature,which allows data to be captured by a single clock and clocked out by two clocks" ?